# Is the space of discrete probabilities measurable in the space of probabilities with weak topology?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $S$ be a polish space and $\mathcal{P}(S)$ be the space of all probability measures with weak topology. I am wondering whether the set of all discrete probability measures is measurable. Thanks very much!